# pass a variable to predefined function sybase/sql

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-iq

i'm new in sql language, and i would appreciate your help. I want to pass a variable (i.e. a column) to a predefined function like "convert" or "hextobigint".

```
select hextobigint('14c9d0742dc')
```

returns 1428563641052

meanwhile the below code doesn't gets executed ()

```
begin 
declare @st varchar(16); 
set @st=dc.table.START_TIME;
select hextobigint('dc.table.START_TIME') FROM dc.table; 
end
```

Error

> Correlation name "table" not found.

Also for the function returns the correct value:

```
select convert (bigint,0x14c9d0742dc)
```

but

```
select convert (bigint,14c9d0742dc)
```

doesn't

> Syntac error 'c9d0742dc' on line 1.

also

```
select convert(bigint,dc.table.START_TIME) FROM dc.table
```

returns only null because the format of the column is like "14c9d0742dc".

The scope is to pass variable (column) to these functions "hextobigint" and "convert". Could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not convert an alphanumeric to a bigint with the convert statement above.  So you would need to change the convert to first convert Hex to Int.  But then you do not need the convert statement as the following two lines return the same value.  So just use the second one.

```
select convert (bigint,hextobigint('0x14c9d0742dc'));
select hextobigint('0x14c9d0742dc');
```

Regarding your first problem the syntax is wrong but I am not sure what you are trying to get back. If you want to convert the column START_TIME from a table called "yourTableName" then you could do this.

```
begin 

select hextobigint(START_TIME) FROM table_raw; 

end
```

Alternatively try this version with dynamic SQL based on the constraint in your comment below.

```
begin 
declare @sql varchar(200);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE WITH RESULT SET ON 'select hextobigint(START_TIME) FROM table_raw;';
end
```

Comment: thank you for your response. my column is in string that represents a HEX value. the format is like this one: "14c9d0742dc" without "0x" before. the second code returns only null...

Comment: What is the name of the table you need to read from which contains the column "START_TIME"?

Comment: Indeed it's "table_raw". I just wanted to demonstrate the case above.

Comment: Then I have updated the SELECT statement above to use this table and it should work for you also.

Comment: Great, it worked! one last thing. can i do this using only "convert" function as in business intelligence from where i'm running query, only "convert" function is available (there is no hextobigint).

Comment: Try using dynamic SQL (see edited answer above with alternative using dynamic SQL.  This might work for you,